# How compare 2 array values string and found identical values or specific values with PHP

Tags: php

This is my problem, let's say I have two **arrays**, each of which has a value of type string as follows:

```
$array1 =array(".dropdown");
$array2 =array(".dropdown-menu > li > a:hover", ".dropdown > li > a:hover", ".dropdown", ".dropdown,.navbar-nav", ".navbar-nav");
```

I want to get value for identical or specifics of the array, I have tried using the following script:

```
foreach($array1 as $value1){
    foreach($array2 as $value2){
        if(stristr($value2, $value1) !== false){
             echo $value2;
             eho "<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

the result is:

```
.dropdown-menu > li > a:hover
.dropdown > li > a:hover
.dropdown
.dropdown,.navbar-nav
```

I do not want `.dropdown-menu> li> a: hover` or `.dropdown-blablabla`, just only to output:

```
.dropdown > li > a:hover
.dropdown
.dropdown,.navbar-nav
```

How to do that with PHP?

Thank you in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem you are asking for items that match based on white space, in other words...

```
".dropdown" = ".dropdown > li > a:hover" is ok
```

but

```
".dropdown" = ".dropdown-menu > li > a:hover" is not
```

because the "-menu" is appended to ".dropdown"

So something like this should work...

```
$array1 =array(".dropdown");
$array2 =array(".dropdown-menu > li > a:hover", ".dropdown > li > a:hover", ".dropdown", ".dropdown,.navbar-nav", ".navbar-nav");

foreach($array1 as $value1){
    foreach($array2 as $value2){
        foreach (explode(' ',$value2) as $value2part){
            if($value1 == $value2part){
                echo $value2;
                ehco "<br />";
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try to apply this one method

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
foreach($array1 as $value1){
    foreach($array2 as $value2){
         $tmp = explode(" ",$value2);
         foreach($tmp as $part_value){
             if($value1 == $part_value){
                 echo $value2;
                 echo "<br />";
             }
         }
     }
}
```

It would look into the pieces of the second arrays elements and compare only those.

Comment: Thanks, still available ".dropdown-menu"